# Did i destroy my windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bootable-media

Ubuntu, as always, is very risky to set up. I believe I selected the option "erase disk" on the USB. It never mentioned Windows, like it did the first time I installed it, earlier tonight. I thought it was referring to the USB itself with a sort of misnomer, and went ahead with that. Now i can't boot Windows 10. Is it really gone? Is there any way I can recover enough memory to boot Windows 10 again?

I tried TestDisk, recovering the disks as best I could, but I still couldn't boot.

I really have to be less careless. I'm not this stupid, just really careless.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you did. Do you see any windows files/folders like "Program files", "Wondows" on any partition? If yes then you only need to fix windows boot-loader. Otherwise it's gone.

Comment: Since you have Ubuntu installed, try getting to GParted to see what (and how many) partitions are present.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to say without more information.

Its possible that Ubuntu erased the entire OS and put itself in its place, in which case you will have limited luck.  (Ubuntu is small, only 4-8 gigs typically) so a lot of the data will be on the physical disk which means Photorec may be able to recover some information)

If Testdisk did actually see (and allow you to restore) the partitions and get data, then your data is probably still there, and one of 2 things has happened - either it has changed your partition table or simply changed the Master Boot Record so you can't boot.       What happened with Testdisk ?

If only the MBR has been overwritten, it is probably possible to recover Windows 7 booting - but we would need to know if you are using GPT or MBR (And, to be honest, I've not fought with Windows and Grub - the Linux boot loader for many years)